# How to detect NSTimer selector called or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, nstimer

```
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(timerFire:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

//if(timerFire not called) {other code}
    }
```

How can I detect if `timerFire:` not called. If `timerFire:` is not called then I want to perform some other activity.

Comment: Add a NSLog and check console log while debugging over simulator.

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly you ask here. Why wouldn't `timerFire:` be called?

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what you're asking here.

In any normal situation the timer is going to fire and thus `timerFire:` will be called.

This will not happen if:

1. you did not actually implement `timerFire:` in the class which you set as a target (so, in this case it's `self`). you can check this with `respondsToSelector:`?
2. the timer is invalidated before the interval of 0.2 sec is over, in that case you can use a global variable in your class (something like `BOOL timerDidFire`) and set it to `YES` in `timerFire:`

Comment: I created a global var, set YES in touchesBegan and set NO in timerFire: but touchesBegan first completes its execution and then timerFire: is called so my if condition always get YES. Can you write small snippet regarding your point 2.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(timerFire:)])
{
// Your Code
}
else
{
}
```